# Java: generic XML reader using reflection

Tags: java, xml, generics, reader

So, I have a class *XmlReader*, that is able to load and return a list of entities of type *Client* (which is defined by me), from an xml file. But, I also may have an xml file having entities of type "Movie" or any other type, and I want that my XmlReader to be able to read and retrieve that from the file.. I heard something that reflection could be used in order to make a generic *XmlReader* class, but I do not know how to do that.. can anyone help me? Thanks in advance! My code for the XmlReader class is:

```
public class XmlReader<ID, T extends MyObject<ID>> 
{
     private String fileName;

     public XmlReader(String fileName) 
     {
         this.fileName = fileName;
     }

     public List<Client> loadEntities() 
     {
         List<Client> entities = new ArrayList<>();
         XmlHelper docXml = new XmlHelper();
         Document document = docXml.loadDocument(this.fileName);
         document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
         NodeList clientElements = root.getElementsByTagName("field");
         int id=-1;
         String name="";
         for (int i=0; i < clientElements.getLength(); i++) 
         {
             Node clientElement = clientElements.item(i);
             Element el = (Element) clientElement;
             if (clientElement.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
             {
                 // ignoring element due to wrong node type
                 continue;
             }
             if (el.hasAttribute("name") && el.getAttribute("name").equals("id")) 
             {
                 id = Integer.parseInt(el.getAttribute("value"));
             }
             if (el.hasAttribute("name") && el.getAttribute("name").equals("name")) 
             {
                 name = el.getAttribute("value");
             }
             if (i % 2 ==1) 
             {
                 Client newClient = new Client(id, name);
                 entities.add(newClient);
             }
          }
      return entities;
  }
}
```

And the xml file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <Clients>
      <entity class="class Domain.Client">
           <field name="name" type="class java.lang.String" value="Liviu"/>
           <field name="id" type="class java.lang.Object" value="1"/>
      </entity>
 </Clients>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting the name of the class from within your XML you could do something like:

```
String className = ... // extract your class name into this
YourClass c = (YourClass) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```